# .bat pause in if statement result in executing else branch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code :

```
IF %cnt% NEQ 10 ( 
    ECHO NÃO EXISTEM 10 FICHEIROS NA PASTA 
    PAUSE 
) ELSE (
    goto :TESTE   
)
```

`%cnt%` is a count and I'm not showing it in this code.

Anyways, my problem is, whenever I get less than 10 files in the folder it should appear the message after the `ECHO` and it does but the problem is when I click to continue in the bat, it executes the else, and it shouldn't be executing it.

Comment: You need to show the code just before and the code just after the snippet you've provided. _My best guess is that the next line of code is `:TESTE`_.

Comment: As @Compo says, show more of your batch file, what you're trying to do _does_ (can) work. Also, to eliminate possible confusion, does "_when I **click** to continue in the bat_" mean pressing the `ENTER` key? Because (AFAIK) you can't _click_ (with a mouse) in response to `PAUSE`... if you _are_ clicking, you might be doing something else!

Answer (score 1):

Then `(` **MUST** be on the same physical line as the `IF`.